# Show and hide div in C# don't work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a web application in C# .net, using twitter bootstrap in frontoffice. 
In onClick button I need to show a div that contains a progressBar div and when the process finish, hide the div. I'm using this code:

**web.aspx**:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClick="btnProcess_Click" />
    // on load web,  this div is invisible
<div class="progress progress-striped active invisible" id="progressBar" runat="server">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 90%;" id="percentProgresBar"></div>
</div>
```

And my **web.aspx.cs**:

```
protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
// here change class to "visible"
progressBar.Attributes["class"] = "progress progress-striped active visible";
//--- all my process ----
//--- all my process ----
//when my process finish, hide the div again, change the css class to "invisible"
progressBar.Attributes["class"] = "progress progress-striped active invisible";
}
```

My problem is the div is visible when my process ends, not at the beginning. How can I resolve this? tTo make visible the div before --- all my process ---- and when finish that part of my code, to make the div invisible again.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You will not be able to affect the element on the server side, you must use client side javascript for this and issue a command asynchronously using something like ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing/converting your div to a server-side control by giving it an **ID** and add **runat="server"** , then use it in your code.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using those classes, give the attribute Style="display:none" to hide and Style="display:" to make it visible but that wont serve your purpose. But for displaying the progress bar you can simply use **Update Progress**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
   <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
     <ProgressTemplate>
         Loading...
     </ProgressTemplate>
 </asp:UpdateProgress>
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" id="upd" onclick="updButton_Click" 
               text="click to update" />
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

In code behind updButton_Click takes a long time to update, during the period you will see Loading... on the page, you can change the text to a  to make it more like a ProgressBar(such as a GIF moving-bar image)

Comment: Update progress placed above your content template in an update panel does the work for you. not only for button click but for any server side events. Remember you need to have a script manager for this. @Patricio